# Creating an appropriate conditional Loop in Java

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to create a simple program with a while loop that will print out "Reward player with bonus." while a variable called "battingAvg" is greater than 0.300, and print out "Not currently eligible for bonus." when that same variable is below 0.300.

below is the code I have written:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[]args) {
    double battingAvg;
    double atBats;
    double hits = 121.0;
    atBats=372;
    battingAvg=hits/atBats;
    while (battingAvg>.300){
        System.out.println("Reward player a bonus");
        atBats=372;
      atBats= atBats+ 10;
    }
    out.println("Not currently eligible for bonus.");
}}
```

For some reason the "atBats" variable in the program doesn't iterate each time through the loop adding +10 to the variable. What am I doing wrong? I am a complete noob to programming any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your while loop, you're doing `atBats=372;`, so you're resetting the value of `atBats` for every iteration of your loop.

Comment: Why would `atBats` iterate? You reset it 372 each time through the loop.  None of that is relevant though, since you never update `battingAvg`, which is what the loop condition is based on...

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop you're resetting the atBats each time to 372 and then adding 10 afterwards, so each turn atBats will end with 382, and the battingAvg is set before the loop, so it has only one value, so the while condition will be always with the battingAvg in the initial value: 121.0/372. If you want to update this you need to delete the atBats=372 from inside the loop and just let the adjustment add up the 10, then add battingAvg = hits/atBats inside the loop to update that to the new atBats value, that will work.
Also just for making it easier to write and read you could use `atBats += 10` and that is the same as `atBats = atBats + 10`

Comment: That still didn't work. Even deleting the varibale atBats from inside the loop still produced an infinite loop.

Comment: The infinite loop is created by the 2 variables, not only the aBats needs to be updated in the loop by 10 if you like, but also inside the loop the average needs to recalculate, otherwise the average will always be the one put before the loop:
while (battingAvg>.300){
        System.out.println("Reward player a bonus");
        atBats=372;
      atBats= atBats+ 10;
        battingAvg = hits/aBats;
    }
it could help if you added to your print the current values of your variables to see them change. System.out.println("...reward stuff..." + aBats + " - " + battingAvg);

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It finally worked. Having to declare the battingAvg variable again inside the while loop seemed redundant to me. I guess all variables subject to variation inside a loop(whether direct or indirect) must be re-declared in all loops for Java.

Comment: Glad I could help, yes if you want a value that does not move, then outside the loop once is alright, but if you need it to work along your loop code then it needs to be taken into account for updating or it will always be the same